# How to stop pygame sprite leaving 'tail'

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

I am having a problem with my pygame/python program. I am using 3.3. A screenshot of what is happening is at:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckKbo.png

Now as you should be able to see when you move the square before dosnt refresh meaning that you leave a trail of your self across the screen. Currently I have this:

```
code to initiate pygame and set background
x=0 #starting cords
y=0
image = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("textures","necromancer.png")) #set image location
running=True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.display.quit()
            running=False
            break
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed() #take key user presses to use in below if/elif statements
        dist = 20 #amount sprite will move when one key is pressed
        if key[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            y += dist
        elif key[pygame.K_UP]:
            y -= dist
        elif key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            x += dist
        elif key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            x -= dist
        screen.blit(image, (x, y))
        print(x)
        print(y)
        pygame.display.update()
```

Any Ideas how I can stop this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember last position and after move repaint it.

When someone press key remember position `old_x = x` and  `old_y = y`.
After the move repaint position on `old_x` and `old_y`.

Comment: Repaint it how? The background is simply 1 large 800x600 image. I can see how that would work if all the background is one colour/texture. Is it possible to have pygame load a part of an image?

Comment: So again add that image.